# Android MVVM ViewModel and Repositories for each entity?

Tags: android, mvvm, android-architecture-components, android-jetpack

With the Android Architecture components and the MVVM pattern I have some question.

Based on most examples around the web there are usually simple examples.

1. Have an entity for Room

```
   @Entity
   public class User{
   ...
   }
```

2. Have a DAO

```
    @Dao
    public interface UserDao{
    ...
    }
```

3. Have a repository

```
   public class UserRepository{
    }
```

4. ViewModel

```
    public class UsersListViewModel extends AndroidViewModel{
    ....
    }
```

Now let's extend this and beside `user` have `user_access` and `user_actions` for instance, so have 3 tables.

Questions:

1. For each table in Room I create entities. Should I have 3 `Dao` one for each entity (userDao, userAccessDao, userActionsDao) or just a general `AppDao` class?
2. Same goes for Repository. One repository for the entire app or Repositories for each Entitiy (RepositoryUser, RepositoryUserAccess, RepositoryUserActions?
3. If my app has one main activity and multiple fragments, should I create one ViewModel for each fragment?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

## 1

You should have contextual DAOs, let's say an UserDao which should contains the queries related to the users, if you have posts in your app, you should have a PostDao for everything related to posts.

## 2

Same logic for repositories, remember the Single Responsibility Principle for classes, sticking to that principle you should have repositories for each kind of entities separated (UserRepository, PostRepository...).

## 3

Following all the new concepts described as Jetpack you should have one viewmodel per fragment, unless for one strange reason you have two fragments that need the exact same logic, and that is very unlikely to happen since the objective of a fragment is to be reused.

Comment: I think we are repeating ourselves and it does not match DRY (Don’t Repeat Yourself) principle, because, we write almost the same codes in both Repository and ViewModel.

Comment: @ErcanDuman You write the logic only once, you use anywhere you need it.

Comment: @EuryPérezBeltré I somewhat agree with you and Ercan's comment. We would be have a lot of redundant code with multiple models, let alone the logic in each of them.

Comment: @Napolean then you guys didn't catch the idea. The viewModels can be shared and repositories can be reused, where specifically will be the redundant code?

Comment: And what if i need to obtain a session_id, stored in another repository in order to get User Details?. @Napolean official documentation says that you can not reuse view models is not a good practice.

Comment: @NestorPerez you can always reuse your repositories. If you have a repository for all things related to the session you can grab the instance in every viewModel if you want.